# Solidity - Execution reverted (how to debug in Remix)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am creating blockchain lottery smart contract that is using my own ERC20 token.

The idea is simple. Players buy any amount of tickets they want. Each ticket that is bought is stored as a pair of *address* and *ticketId*.

When the manager calls the *pickWinner()* function, a random number is generated and one ticket is chosen as the winning one.

All is working good until I call the *pickWinner()* function. After I try to call it I get the following error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted { "originalError": { "code": 3, "data": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032", "message": "execution reverted" } }
```

The problem is, it's not telling me where the problem is. I don't know how to proceed further without trying removing line by line and see where's the problem.

Here's the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Lottery {

    event TicketsBought(address playerAddress, uint256 quantity, uint256 ticketPrice);
    event WinnerPicked(ticket ticket, uint256 amount);

    struct ticket {
        address walletAddress;
        uint256 ticketId;
    }

    uint256 currentTicketId = 0;

    address gamblinoAddress = 0xE9FEA6A6A1a8BB99E0C888c93A06D22f804A5fFA;
    uint public ticketPrice = 50 * 10**18;
    address public manager;
    ticket public winner;
    ticket[] public tickets;

    uint256 public balance;

    constructor() {
        manager = msg.sender;
        balance = 0;
    }

    function getPlayerAddresses() private view returns (address[] memory) {
        address[] memory addresses;

        for(uint i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++) {
             addresses[i] = tickets[i].walletAddress;
        }

        return addresses;
    }

    function buyTickets(uint256 quantity) public payable {
        uint256 amount = ticketPrice * quantity;
        GamblinoToken gamblinoToken = GamblinoToken(gamblinoAddress);
        uint256 allowance = gamblinoToken.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        uint256 playerBalance = gamblinoToken.balanceOf(msg.sender);
        require(playerBalance >= amount, 'Check token balance');
        require(allowance >= amount, 'Check the token allowance');

        balance = balance + amount;

        for (uint i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            ticket memory t = ticket(msg.sender, currentTicketId);
            tickets.push(t);
            currentTicketId++;
        }

        gamblinoToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        emit TicketsBought(msg.sender, quantity, ticketPrice);

    }

    function random() public view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, getPlayerAddresses())));
    }

    function pickWinner() public {
        uint index = random() % tickets.length;
        uint256 amount = balance;

        GamblinoToken gamblinoToken = GamblinoToken(gamblinoAddress);
        // the entitre balance of this contract to the winner.
        gamblinoToken.transfer(tickets[index].walletAddress, balance);
        // set balance to 0
        balance = 0;
        // set winner
        winner = tickets[index];
        // reset ticket id
        currentTicketId = 0;
        // clear players and start over.
        delete tickets;

        emit WinnerPicked(winner, amount);
    }

    function getTickets() public view returns (ticket[] memory) {
        return tickets;
    }

    // restrict to only the manager (the contract creator)
    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }
}

interface ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

contract GamblinoToken is ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {}
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint) {}
    function transfer(address receiver, uint numTokens) public override returns (bool) {}
    function approve(address delegate, uint numTokens) public override returns (bool) {}
    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {}
    function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint numTokens) public override returns (bool) {}
}
```

Comment: I deployed the contract but I am not even able to call the buyTicket function?  are you able to?

Comment: yes, you need to have my custom token in order to call this function. If you want, send me your address, and I can send you some tokens. Also, before calling buyTicket() function you need to do the approval for that amount for the Lottery smart contract to be allowed to spend your tokens. I can send you the source of the token contract too, so that you can call that function. And, btw tokens are created on ropsten testnet

Comment: how are you able to call the GamblinoToken functions. you did not implement anything. if you did not implement anything how the information will be stored on the blockchain.